# Why do people leave unused `String args[]` in Java?

Tags: java, arguments, command-line-arguments

When I see Java programs, many leave the `String args[]` on even though the program doesn't use them. Why is this? Anything in particular?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1672083/139010

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`String args[]` is part of the method signature for main. If you don't have it you will get the exception below when you try and run the code.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/5KQYZ1VV This runs fine for me, though...

Comment: I get the exception when I use the java compiler for mac (version javac 1.6.0_45). What compiler are you using?

Comment: javac 1.7.0_10 on OSX 10.7

Comment: I don't have that specific compiler on my computer. When I tried it with a javac version 1.7.0_11 on Fedora. I got a `Error: Main method not found in class tut21, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)` So I do not know why you can run it. You shouldn't be able to.

Comment: @MarJamRob, either your compiler is broken or you're not running the class file you think you are. JLS7 explicitly states the parameter is required (see KevinB's answer).

Answer (score 7):

If it is for a `main(String[])` it is to fulfill the method signature & therefore vital.

Answer (score 3):

Its required by the specification.

> > The method main must be declared public, static, and void. It must
> >     specify a formal parameter (§8.4.1) whose declared type is array of
> >     String. Therefore, either of the following declarations is acceptable:
>
> public static void main(String[] args)
>
> public static void main(String... args)

[Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4)

Answer (score 2):

The code within the main may not directly use it, but it is still required. 'String args[]' is where any command line arguments are passed. Even if you pass in 0 arguments, there needs to be a way for that to be verified. It is also the required signature for main by the requirements of the JVM.