# Error: Could not find or load main class in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: java, eclipse-kepler

Writing a simple program in Eclipse Kepler I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class
```

I already tried the options listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334625/eclipse-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class), though the options the answers suggest do not seem to exist in Kepler.  For example, there is no 'build Automatically' button to check as the accepted answer suggests. Here is the photographic proof:  [image]

Code is as follows:

```
public class keplertest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

Unable to 'add' the main class under the 'projects' heading either.  [image]

Comment: Could you post your code.  Specifically interested in the main method and the way you invoke the app/class in the first place.

Comment: Code posted, thanks!  :)

Comment: @Chris:  it might be the same error, but I don't see how to use the same resolution in Kepler...

Comment: The existing stackoverflow questions on this same topic are not addressing Eclipse Kepler, which seems to be quite different from other versions IMO...

Comment: clean your project. and try again

Answer (score 0):

Your main method should be:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

the `String[] args` is required as that is the method signature Java looks for when launching your Java program

For more information why `String[] args` is required: [Why is String[] args required in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672083/why-is-string-args-required-in-java)

Also, the "build automatically" reference is pointing to the project *menu bar* item, not in the window.

Comment: That's in the code, same error...

Comment: Also, what is the 'project menu' bar?  I do not see one in Kepler.  Are you using Kepler?

Comment: Yes i am using kepler. There should be a project dropdown where File/Refactor/Help etc. are located.  The recommendations in the other stack overflow questions do exist in kepler as well.

Answer (score 0):

From the same Properties window Select `Run/Debug`

If your launching class doesn't exist in that list, you need to add it by clicking <kbd>New</kbd> - `Java Application`, then in the dialog <kbd>Search</kbd> for your class in the `Main Class` text field. That should give your project a Main launching class

**And/OR** try to go to **Run as -> Run Configuration** from the project context menu. In the `Main Class` text field put in the fully qualified name of the launching class

You may need to clean an build afterwards