# Why is String[] args required in main method..?

Tags: java

Why is String[] args required in main method.. why not Object[] although Object can contains of String or even any type of objects.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890966/what-is-string-args-parameter-in-main-method-java

Comment: Its holding startup parameters, that you provide when starting the programm. How would you pass an object?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672083/why-is-string-args-required-in-java

Comment: you always pass String as parameters .