# public static void main(String args[]) why string args[] is compulsory ,why we not use public static void main(Object args[])?

Tags: java

why we not use Object args[] it can also hold any type of data.

```
class Demo {
    public static void main(Object args[]) {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: The main entry point of a program usually receives `String` arguments through a command line call and `String` arguments can hold obects, maybe in JSON or XML.

Comment: [Because the JLS says so](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4).

Comment: It harks all the way back to good old C days (and probably earlier).  The only parameters which can be sent to the "main" method/function (when the program is launched) are string based, I mean, how do you send a "object" via the CLI anyway?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is String\[\] args required in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672083/why-is-string-args-required-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

The main method receives its arguments from the command line, which in most (all?) OSes is string oriented. In other words, the information that Java will receive to call `main`, will already be in string form (and only string), so using `Object[]` for `main` would require programmers to add explicit casts to `String` each time they would want to use an argument as a string. Using `String[]` is therefor more logical, and leads to simpler code.

And of course, as [Turing85](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4216641/turing85) said in the comments, the legalistic point of view is that this is ["because the JLS says so"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4):

> The method `main` must be declared `public`, `static`, and `void`. It
> must specify a formal parameter (§8.4.1) whose declared type is array
> of `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you cannot pass an object via a command line argument.